# NgModel value not reflected in textbox

Tags: angular, angular6

Hello i am working on angular 6 application.
I have a list which vlaues are simultaneously changing and values in the object are also changing but they are not reflected while rendering on UI textbox using `ngFor`.
Here is the sample code.
**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of list; let i = index">
   <div>{{elem.name}}</div>
   <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="elem.weight" name="weight_{{i}}"/>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
public list = [{name:"ABC",weight:20},{name:"XYZ",weight:50},{name:"PQR",weight:70}];

public change(){//called internally
  this.list[1].weight = 40;
}
```

Here, 
Data is updated in list but in textbox i can see the old value it is not getting updated.
I don't know why is this happening even if names of textboxes are different.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcqdub. Post a stackblitz that reproduces the problem. Also, don't use [value] on your inut. You already have ngModel that sets the value.

Comment: removing [value] also does not work

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `[(ngModel)]` there is no need to set `[value]`

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="elem.weight"  name="weight_{{i}}"/>
```

Here is a working sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k96cca

Comment: it does not works if any object is pushed or removed or index is changed

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? I modified Joels example. Take a look. I think everything is working. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4rqv4

Comment: @YogeshKatkar are sure that the code is not working ?. my satckblitz demo is working though. can you recreate the issue with your stackblitz code